# How to visualise chess moves using a TikZ tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I am building a chess repertoire and would like to visualise it as a tree using TikZ.

Below is an example of what I would like do achieve (source: https://kevinbinz.com/2015/02/26/decision-trees-in-chess/)

- round nodes with alternated color,
- moves on edges,
- text in a last rectangular node (evaluation of the position).

Exact font, color code, node decoration and arrow shape are irrelevant.

[image: example]

*Note.* Any data can be used in the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be enough to get you started:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{end node/.style={draw,rectangle, fill=green!30,minimum width=1cm},
           chess tree/.style={for tree={align=center,edge={-latex},s sep=1cm,l sep=1cm,
           where n children=0{end node, edge={-}}{delay={draw, circle,minimum size=1cm, 
           if={iseven(level())}{fill=white}{fill=black!20}}}}},
           move/.style={if n=1{edge label={node[midway,left]{#1}}}
                              {edge label={node [midway, right]{#1}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}chess tree
[
    [,move=Be3,
        [,move=g5
            [{[1a]\\-3}]
        ]
    ] 
    [,move=Bh6
        [{[2a]\\-2}]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for your time

Comment: @Victor I'd be really interested in your final result. Would you mind posting it once you're done? :)

Comment: With pleasure! :)

Comment: @Victor I've made a couple of changes to the code to removed the arrow from the final branch, and removed a spurious `end node` that wasn't needed in the tree.

Comment: This is a bit cleaner indeed, thank you! What I am currently struggling with is spacing correctly the branches when there are a lot of them (let's say five or six). After that I'll send you the result